# Von Neumann Algebra isomorphism extension

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I have Von Neumann algebra $\mathfrak{U}$ and a weakly dense *-subalgebra $A$. I have another Von Neumann Algebra $\mathfrak{V}$ and an injective *-homorphism $$\phi: A\longrightarrow \mathfrak{V}$$ such that $\phi(A)$ generates $\mathfrak{V}$. Is it possible to say that one can extend $\phi$ to an *-isomorphism from $\mathfrak{U}$ onto $\mathfrak{V}$?

P.D. In fact the case I am interested in is when A is a Hilbert algebra and $\mathfrak{V}$ is the natural Von Neumann Algebra of A as defined by Dixmier in its books C *-Algebras or Von Neumann Algebras. I however believe the question as posted has all the required ingredients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  This will almost never be true (subalgebras of the compacts are the only cases I can think of where it could work). The easiest example is probably $C[0,1].$  It has an injective homomorphism to $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$--by point evaluation at the rationals--that generates $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$.  It also sits inside $L^\infty[0,1].$  But $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ has minimal projections and $L^\infty[0,1]$ doesn't.

Comment: Do you think if I know that the Von Neumann algebras involved are Type I it will make a difference?

Comment: @Carlos De la Mora No it won't make a difference.  The example I gave is Type I.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt I want to ask a silly question: Why $\phi(C[0,1])$ generates $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @C.Ding Just to be clear; the claim is that $\phi(C[0,1])$ generates $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ as a von Neumann algebra.  So it suffices to show that $\phi(C[0,1])$ is w*-dense in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}).$ Let $e_n$ be a minimal projection in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}).$  Let $q$ be a rational corresponding to $e_n.$  Take a sequence of uniformly bounded continuous functions $f_k$ with $f_k(q)=1$ whose support shrinks to $\{ q \}.$  Then $\phi(f_k)\rightarrow e_n$ in the w*-topology.

Answer (score 4):

You can give a characterisation of when it holds.  Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $A$ is closed, i.e. is a C$^*$-algebra.  Consider the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra, which I will consider as being the bidual $A^{**}$.  If $\phi:A\rightarrow\mathfrak{M}$ is a $*$-homomorphism with $\phi(A)$ weak$^*$-dense in $\mathfrak{M}$ then there is a unique extension $\tilde\phi:A^{**}\rightarrow\mathfrak{M}$ which is a surjective, weak$^*$-continuous $*$-homomorphism.

As $A$ generates $A^{**}$, your question has a positive answer if and only if $\tilde\phi$ is always an isomorphism.  This is equivalent (consider the kernel of $\tilde\phi$) to $A^{**}$ having no proper weak$^*$-closed ideals.  In turn, this is equivalent to $A^*$ having no proper $A$-invariant closed subspaces; and is equivalent to $A^{**}$ having no non-trivial central projections.

See Volume 1 of Takesaki, Section III, Chapter 2.

(I presume that $\mathfrak{U}'$, in your question, is not the commutant of $\mathfrak{U}$.  This is slightly unfortunate notation...)

Comment: Can anything be said on how rare or common it is for $A^{**}$ to have no non-trivial central projections? Currently the only (infinite-dimensional) example I can think of is K(H).

Comment: Urgh, I don't know enough.  Can the universal enveloping algebra be a factor of type II or III ??

Comment: The question did ask for an injective *-homomorphism so this doesn't quite give a characterization. For example, the answer is certainly yes for any finite dimensional C*-algebra (the double duals of which can of course have many weak*-closed ideals).

Comment: @YemonChoi In the case that $A$ is separable, then $K(H)$ is the only example.  In the general case this is called Naimark's problem and wades into set theory.

Comment: @MatthewDaws First, I have no idea why my first comment is mostly in italics, my edits don't seem to do anything.  Second, any C*-algebra has an irreducible representation so their double duals always have a non-trivial Type I summand

Comment: @CalebEckhardt non-mathematical comment: the asterisk symbol is used by Markdown, or whatever SE uses, to enclose text in italics. I think the parser is fine if there is only one asterisk, but as soon as there are two, well, italics ahoy